# Maven failed to resolve dependencies - javax.activation

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have a working maven web application which uses many jars. Trying to add javax.activation and do a mvn clean install fails.

I get "Failed to execute goal on project xxx: Could not resolve dependencies for project javax.activation:activation:jar:1.0.2 in central (http://build02.efollett.com:8081/artifactory/libs-release)

When I check my maven repository I see the activation jar there. For example, navigating to C:\Users\me.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.0.2 I see the following.

```
activation-1.0.2.jar.lastUpdated
activation-1.0.2.pom
activation-1.0.2.pom.sha1
activation-1.0.2.pom.tmp.sha1.tmp
```

My colleague is using the same settings.xml and I have compared my local pom.xml to the version in cvs. They are all the same! Any thoughts on what I am missing?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Go to `http://build02.efollett.com:8081/artifactory/libs-release` in your browser and see it contains the particular jar.

Comment: When I follow the path to version 1.0.2 of activation I see 3 files.activation-1.0.2.pom 21-Dec-2005 09:36  289 bytes
activation-1.0.2.pom.md5   21-Dec-2005 09:36  32 bytes
activation-1.0.2.pom.sha1  21-Dec-2005 09:36  40 bytes     I assume I should see a .jar file there as well. Our setup is such that if the jar is not in our artifactory it pulls it down from the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The artifact you need is `javax.activation:activation:jar:1.0.2` (pay attention to the `jar` part), while the artifact you have in your repo is `javax.activation:activation:pom:1.0.2`. Either place a `jar` one into your repo or add `<classifier>pom</classifier>` to your `<dependency>`.

Comment: Thanks! The issue was that our artifcatory didn't have the jar, but had the pom.xml or something like that. So, I think maven was expecting the jar to be there and kept failing when it didn't find it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10):

Sun will not allow Maven to redistribute its binaries, including JavaMail JAR and Activation JAR. Instead, all users must install Sun binaries manually by downloading them from Sun's website and running the mvn install command.

**1. Download Java Activation Framework**

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jaf-136260.html

and then

http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jaf/1.0.2-fcs/jaf-1_0_2-upd2.zip

**2. Extract "jaf-1.0.2"**

**3. Run at folder "jaf-1.0.2"**

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=activation.jar -DgroupId=javax.activation -DartifactId=activation -Dversion=1.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar`

Answer (score 1):

Add dependency to your pop.xml file

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
<artifactId>activation</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
```

Comment: Maybe more recently updated here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/javax.activation-api